# Do I need to sanitize input from ASP.NET MembershipProvider controls?

Tags: asp.net, security, validation, sanitization

I'm using various ASP.NET controls out of the box such as the CreateUserWizard control, Login control etc... For custom controls, I have sanitized my inputs by making sure they conform to expected values. However, is this required for the controls such as the CreateUserWizard control, or is that handled internally? Do I need to provide any extra server side validation to these controls and, if so, would it be best to do it in the "CreateUserWizardControl_CreatingUser" event?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of input sanitization are you refering to? That is, what kind of inputs do *you* consider to be invalid that you are worried that ASP.NET might consider are valid?

Comment: I'm not an expert on security, so I may be providing unnecessary validation. But, for example, if the user injected certain script as the 'Username', would the control automatically encode the script and remove '<script>something</script>'characters or would it embed it into the database as is? When outputting, I could always encode it, but I'd rather not have potentially dangerous code in the DB in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If input is coming from any form, then treat it as suspect. I've included some links here that may help you:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/11/01/ASPNET-Data-Input-Validation.aspx

Comment: Thank you, IrishChieftain. That link is great. I guess extra validation is worth the slight increase in overhead compared to a potentially costly attack. I've already created a few Regex methods in my util class, so I'll pass MembershipProvider controls through them as well.

Comment: Most people don't consider anything other than forms - there are so many ways a hacker can get in. Keep an eye on CAT.NET :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have request validation enabled then form data with script tags will generate an error automatically.

Comment: The <script> was just an example. I'm still reading up on security, so there are no doubt other bits of code that could be injected, yet look valid.